# Codeblocks can build C program but can't run it

Tags: c, macos, codeblocks

I am new on MacOS this is why I don't really know how it works.

When I build my C program in Codeblocks I have no issue with the compiler, but when I am trying to run it I get the following error :

```
'/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/gabin/Documents/codeblocks/fd/bin/Debug/fd '
zsh: no such file or directory: /Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/gabin/Documents/codeblocks/fd/bin/Debug/fd
```

I saw in a different post that this is a problem of a space in the program name, but the name of the program is "fd" here, so I don't see where is the problem.

Comment: Does the file exist: `/Users/gabin/Documents/codeblocks/fd/bin/Debug/fd`? And if it does, does this file exist: `/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner`?

Comment: There's also the issue that the first line appears to have a space at the end `.../Debug/fd '`

Comment: @user3386109 Hello, thanks for your answer, I checked the two files are existing. For your second comment there is a space at the end but it is not a space in the name of the program. Is it possible to remove it ?

Comment: That's a good question. Someone more experienced with Codeblocks will have to answer that.

Comment: It appears that CodeBlocks is trying to use that whole string as a single filename, whereas whoever wrote it appears to have intended it to be interpreted as a shell command (and hence parsed into several pieces and subjected to shell parameter expansion, with the trailing space character being insignificant).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, I understand the idea but can you guide me to run my program from my Mac terminal ?

Comment: What are the single quote characters doing there? They are wrong,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *Settings -> Environment* and change *"Terminal to launch console programs"* with:

```bash
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script "$SCRIPT"' -e 'end tell'
```

this will remove the `quoted form of` from the default value.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add custom run commands in Codeblocks, use this

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/gabin/Documents/codeblocks/fd/bin/Debug/fd
```

It should just be environment variable followed by a binary, with any number of spaces between arguments (inter arguments, not intra arguments).

I don't know about Codeblocks, but Xcode accepts .app bundle as launch item. If you want to launch anything from Terminal, use the full path to the main binary

```
/Users/gabin/Documents/codeblocks/fd/bin/Debug/fd
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy/paste the command without the quotes '   ':

```
/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/gabin/Documents/codeblocks/fd/bin/Debug/fd
```

and it will run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the quotes ' ' around the command. If you copy/paste the command without the quotes it will execute the code. Here is an example according to the above question:

```
/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/gabin/Documents/codeblocks/fd/bin/Debug/fd
```

It may vary for others.